# Multiple Taps Required in UITableView for Checkmarks

Tags: ios, didselectrowatindexpath, uitableview

Be gentle, I'm learning.

The code below actually works fine except for the fact that after I tap a row for the first time (which appropriately places a checkmark), I then have to tap a cell twice to get it to remove that same checkmark.

Similarly, after removing it, it requires two taps to put the checkmark back.

How do I fix this?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *thisCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSInteger selectedRow = indexPath.row;

    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
        if (selectedRow == 0) dm = 1;
        else if (selectedRow == 1) athero1 = 1;
        else if (selectedRow == 2) athero2 = 1;
        else if (selectedRow == 3) athero3 = 1;
        else if (selectedRow == 4) familyHistory1 = 1;
        else if (selectedRow == 5) familyHistory2 = 1;
    }
    else  {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        if (selectedRow == 0) dm = 0;
        else if (selectedRow == 1) athero1 = 0;
        else if (selectedRow == 2) athero2 = 0;
        else if (selectedRow == 3) athero3 = 0;
        else if (selectedRow == 4) familyHistory1 = 0;
        else if (selectedRow == 5) familyHistory2 = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the your didSelectRowAtIndexPath called when you tap on the cell? Did you check that thisCell belongs to the same object?

Answer (score 2):

make sure `allowsMultipleSelection` is not set to `YES`. The default value set when this property is not used is `NO`. In case if you are using this property anywhere in your class then try setting it to `NO` to check if it works. This will cause requiring 2 taps for selecting a row.

```
self.tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = NO;
```

Answer (score 1):

*Have an array to store the selected row indices. In **-didSelect**, check whether the row index already present in the array, if not add it, else remove it from the array. And reload table. Thats all. I believe this would work. :]*

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you are pushing two UITableViewControllers onto your navigation controller stack?

I had this happen to me, and the problem was a missing 'break' in a switch statement that caused a second TableViewController to get pushed. Everything on the view required two taps, even my 'Back' button.